# How to bind Objective-C initXXX method to Xamarin.iOS's constructor, which has same types of arguments?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In Objective-C, sometimes there are multiple initXXX methods which have same type of arguments.
For example,

```
    -(id)initWithImageArray:(NSArray *)images;

    -(id)initWithPNGorJPEGDataArray:(NSArray *)data;
```

If we prepare to bind it to Xamarin.iOS by Objective Sharpie, OS creates such template:

```
    // -(id)initWithImageArray:(NSArray *)images;
    [Export ("initWithImageArray:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (NSObject [] images);

    // -(id)initWithPNGorJPEGDataArray:(NSArray *)data;
    [Export ("initWithPNGorJPEGDataArray:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (NSObject [] data);
```

But these c# interfaces are same, so it cannot compile successfully.

Are there any strategy to bind such type of Objective-C libraries?

Thanks,
Ko-hei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways. The simplest is to figure out (from the documentation of your library) what's the type used inside the `NSArray`.

E.g. *if* the first case is documented as an array of `UIImage` and the second *was* documented as a array of `NSData`

```
-(id)initWithImageArray:(NSArray *)images; // array of UIImage
-(id)initWithPNGorJPEGDataArray:(NSArray *)data; // array of NSData
```

Then it can be bound as

```
IntPtr Constructor (UIImage [] images);

IntPtr Constructor (NSData [] data);
```

That would give both constructors different signatures, compile correctly and make a better binding (as it would be more typesafe than using `NSObject`).